# Is jQuery.off() needed when you use one()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

if I bind an event handler with `one()` (I only want it to run once), do I still need to unbind it with `off()` after the event handler finishes?

```
$(el).one('transitionend', function(e){
  $(el).off('transitionend');                               is this necessary?
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `$.off()` is not needed at all. Once the event fires once, the handler is removed.

Answer (score 1):

No and the answer can be found on this page: http://api.jquery.com/one/

"The handler is removed after the first time the event occurs at the delegated element, whether the selector matched anything or not."

"In other words, explicitly calling .off() from within a regularly-bound handler has exactly the same effect."